# $F=p_1\times p_2$ a hyperbolic space?

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, hyperbolic-geometry

Consider the space of parametrized curves $p_1,$ $x=e^{\log(n_i)e^t}$ $y=e^{\log(n_i)e^{-t}}$ for $-\infty<\Re(t)<\infty$ and $n_i\in(0,1)$ for each $i.$ Revolve the space of parametrized curves about $y=x.$ Create a new parametrization $p_2$, $1-x$ and $y.$ Revolve the space of new parametrized curves about $y=1-x.$ Take the Cartesian product $F=p_1\times p_2$ of the curves in each parametrization. Can the space $F$ be equipped with some type of modified hyperbolic metric based on the combination of $p_1$ and $p_2?$ Assume that one can treat the space of $p_1$ as a lorentzian space, likewise for $p_2,$ leading to hyperbolic spaces and metrics for each. But I'm not sure if $F$ is also a hyperbolic space. Since the product of two constant curvature spaces is not constant anymore I have doubts that $F$ could be a hyperbolic space. Thanks very much.

Comment: I don't understand what $p_1$ and $p_2$ are. What are the elements of the sets $p_1$ and $p_2$? What are the topologies and metrics on these sets?

Comment: The elements of $p_1$ would be the infinite space of the family of curves given by the parametrization. So for example, $x=e^{\log(.5)e^t}$ and $y=e^{\log(.5)e^{-t}}$ would be one such curve in the family of curves.

Comment: The metrics on the space are lorentzian, so that's why, from what I understand, since hyerbolic geometry lives in Minkowski space, you can look at hyperbolic geometry and put a hyperbolic metric on the space

Comment: So, if I understand, the set $p_1$ is in one-to-one correspondence with the open interval $(0,1)$, where element $n_i \in (0,1)$ corresponds to element of $p_1$ which is the parameterized curve $x = e^{\log(n_i) e^t}$, $y = e^{\log(n_i) e^{-t}}$ which is an element of $p_1$. Is this correct?

Comment: Similarly, $p_2$ is in one-to-one correspondence with $(0,1)$. And therefore $F$ is in one-to-one correspondence with the open square $(0,1) \times (0,1)$. Correct?

Comment: Yep that's correct